# Random numbers with different probability of ocurring

Tags: excel, random, probability, montecarlo

I'm simulating a problem in Excel to prove my theoretical result.

I have a total number of customers, let's say `n = 80`. 40% of this group is female and 70% is of the age from 40 to 60. On paper, if I want to get a group of female that is of the age from 40 to 60, I can just multiply `0.4 * 0.7 * 80`

However, I'm running a `Monte Carlo` simulation on Excel, so the sex and the age have to be random here. I can't figure out how to "simulate" the 40% and 70% here. For example, if I do `rand()` and take `1` for male and `0` for female, that would give 50% female though right?

Can I get help with this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert Rand to 1 or 0 in the appropriate ratios. i.e.,:

```
=IF(RAND()>0.7,1,0)
```

Will give a value of 0 70% of the time and 1 the other 30% of the time.